# React won't map over an array of objects, TypeError: data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, axios, react-router-dom

I am following Brad Traversy's React front to back course and I have requested from the github API with axios in app.js

This is the initial state of App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    users: [],
    user: {},
    loading: false,
    alert: null,
  };
```

This is the API call in App.js

```
searchUsers = async (text) => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    console.log(text);
    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${text}&client_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}`
    );

    this.setState({ users: res.data.items, loading: false });
    console.log(res.data.items);
  };
```

Then my Users component takes the users from the state but here is my entire main app.js root render()

```
render() {
    // destrcuturing so no need for this.state in Users component when passing props
    const { users, loading, alert, user } = this.state;

    return (
      <Router>
        <div className='App'>
          <Navbar />

          <div className='container'>
            <Alert alert={alert} />

            <Switch>
              <Route
                exact
                path='/'
                render={(props) => (
                  <Fragment>
                    <Search
                      searchUsers={this.searchUsers}
                      clearUsers={this.clearUsers}
                      showClear={users.length > 0 ? true : false}
                      setAlert={this.setAlert}
                    />
                    <Users loading={loading} users={users} />
                  </Fragment>
                )}
              />

              <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
              <Route
                exact
                path='/user/:login'
                render={(props) => (
                  <User
                    {...props}
                    getUser={this.getUser}
                    user={user}
                    loading={loading}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
```

I console.log the users data in the searchUsers method and in the Users component where I am mapping over this array. The output is clearly an array of objects https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYRYF.jpg

When I load my app from the homepage and search a name it works and renders/maps over the users I can click on the More button for an individual user. However, when I go back using the back to search button in the navbar I get the error that users.map is not a function. I am running node version 14.5.0

Here is Users.js

```
const Users = ({ loading, users }) => {
  console.log('users are a ' + typeof users + ' it looks like below');
  console.log(users);

  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  } else {
    return (
      <div style={userStyle}>
        {users.map((user) => (
          <UserItem user={user} key={user.id} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

and my Navbar.js

```
const Navbar = ({ icon, title }) => {
  return (
    <nav className='navbar bg-primary'>
      <h1>
        <i className={icon}></i>
        {title}
      </h1>

      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to='/about'>About</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

Here is my User component which is what is rendered when the more button is clicked in UserItem.js

```
export class User extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUser(this.props.match.params.login);
  }

  static propTypes = {
    loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    user: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    getUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  render() {
    const {
      name,
      avatar_url,
      location,
      bio,
      blog,
      login,
      html_url,
      followers,
      following,
      public_repos,
      public_gists,
      hirable,
    } = this.props.user;

    const { loading } = this.props;

    if (loading) return <Spinner />;

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Link to='/' className='btn btn-light'>
          Back to search
        </Link>
        Hireable: {''}
        {/* {hireable ? (
          <i className='fas fa-check text-success' />
        ) : (
          <i className='fas fa-times-circle text-danger' />
        )} */}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

The error is reproduced on different steps sometimes when I click on the more button on a user the User.js component does not render however the Navbar is there and no errors are produced but I get users.map is not a function when I click the Navbar home. Other times like I said above the User.js does render and I get the same error whether I click home in the Navbar or the back to search button.

Comment: Just wanna share a way that I usually use to debug. You can just type ```debugger``` right after your else case and run the code step by step.

Comment: can you show the initial state from app.js?

Comment: Which file is it showing the error is in? Because I don't see `data.map` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Users.js has the data.map 3rd piece of code from the bottom